# Why Will the Conditional Split Object in SSIS Only Allow Me to Use 2 && Operators and No More?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I am using the ConditionalSplit Method in SSIS to delete incomplete records.  The following is the condition script"

`[A] != "" && [B] != "" && [C] != "" && [D] != ""`

and it will not accept it.

So I deleted the last column one to make it:

`[A] != "" && [B] != "" && [C] != ""`

and then it would accept it.

Is there a limit that SSIS allows for parameters when using the && operator?

Any Ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can use `[A]+[B]+[C]+[D] != ""`

Answer (score 0):

No, you can put as many `&&` as you wish into a Conditional Split. You've done something in formulating your question's version of the expression and what your actual expression is.

I created a simple data flow

[image]

My source query is `SELECT '1' AS A, '2' AS B, '3' AS C, '4' AS D;`

In my Conditional Split, I have your supplied formula

[image]

The editor accepts that value and you can see that it runs just fine.

[image]

### Reproduction

For those wishing to follow along at home, grab the latest copy of [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/) and use the following Biml, after adjusting for a valid Connection Manager

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <OleDbConnection Name="CM_OLE" ConnectionString="Data Source=localhost\dev2012;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;"></OleDbConnection>
    </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package ConstraintMode="Linear" Name="so_21867229">
            <Tasks>
                <Dataflow Name="DFT">
                    <Transformations>
                        <OleDbSource ConnectionName="CM_OLE" Name="OLE_SRC Query">
                            <DirectInput>SELECT '1' AS A, '2' AS B, '3' AS C, '4' AS D;</DirectInput>
                        </OleDbSource>
                        <ConditionalSplit Name="CSPL Test">
                            <OutputPaths>
                                <OutputPath Name="Foo" >
                                    <Expression>[A] != "" &amp;&amp; [B] != "" &amp;&amp; [C] != "" &amp;&amp; [D] != ""</Expression>
                                </OutputPath>
                            </OutputPaths>
                        </ConditionalSplit>
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```